# Adding separate class to buttons using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating a dynamic list with jQuery. For every new list item that I add to the list, I want to create an Edit Button with a class of "edit" and a Delete Button with a class of "delete."

here is an example in HTML of what I'm trying to achieve

```
    <li>vincent price<button class="edit">Edit</button><button 
    class="delete">Delete</button></li>

    <li><span>Peter Cushing</span><button class="edit">Edit</button>
    <button class="delete">Delete</button></li>

    <input type="text" class="enter">
    <button id="click">Click Here!</button>
```

But i'm having trouble adding the right class to the right button when ever I add new list items. Here is my code:

```
    var editButton = $('<button />').text('edit')
    var deleteButton = $('<button />').text('delete')

    $("#click").click(function(){
     var entry = $(".enter").val()
     $("ul").append("<li><span>" + entry + "</span></li>")

     $(editButton).appendTo('ul li:last-child').addClass('edit');
     $(deleteButton).appendTo('ul li:last-child').addClass('delete');
    });
```

Obviously, the 'ul li:last-child' selector is not working because once you create a new list item, it deletes the buttons from the older ones. But i've been wracking my brain trying to figure out how to solve this. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that convoluted code, why not just put it all in one nice `append` tag, like this:

```
$("#click").click(function() {
    var entry = $(".enter").val();
    $("ul").append("<li><span>" + entry + "</span><button class=\"edit\">Edit</button><button class=\"delete\">Delete</button></li>");
});
```

This should work fine for your needs.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to disable the click event though. Here is the jsfiddle:

Comment: The `edit` and `delete` buttons don't seem to be working even on the ones that have been added previously.

Comment: My bad! I didn't escape the quotes properly. I've edited the answer. Please check now?

Answer (score 0):

Add the class when you create the button. Then you should be fine.

**EDIT**

To append copies of the button, use the jQuery [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents-deepWithDataAndEvents) method. I haven't used it here but there is an optional `WithDataAndEvents` parameter you can use to copy event handlers. Personally I'd use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```js
var editButton = $('<button />').text('edit').addClass('edit');
var deleteButton = $('<button />').text('delete').addClass('delete');

$("#click").click(function() {
  var entry = $(".enter").val()
  $("ul").append("<li><span>" + entry + "</span></li>")

  $(editButton.clone()).appendTo('ul li:last-child');
  $(deleteButton.clone()).appendTo('ul li:last-child');
});
```

```css
.edit {
  color: green;
}

.delete {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
<button id="click">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that. It appears you can't add the addClass method in a variable in jQuery

Comment: What do you mean? This works if you run the code snippet.

Comment: If you hit "click me" multiple times, the edit and delete buttons only appear for the last list item. I think the issue is :last-child doesn't work as a selector.

Answer (score 0):

One of the variant to solve problem with support es6 syntax

```
$("#click").on('click',(e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     const entry = $(".enter").val();
     const template = `
      <li>
         <span>${entry}</span>
         <button class="edit">Edit</button>
         <button class="delete">Delete</button>
      </li>`;

      $('ul').append(template);
   });
```